# One Tailed Confidence Interval

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, linear-regression

I need to draw 95% one tailed confidence interval according to my graph. I struggled to draw it but I didn't so I need your help.

This linear regression graph I need to create 95% confidence line upper my fit line

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st

st.t.interval(0.95, len(data.PPV.values) - 1,
              loc=np.mean(data.PPV.values),
              scale=st.sem(data.PPV.values))
```

Finally, I have to create one tailed confidence interval and I need to draw it on my graph.

Comment: you want a CI of *what exactly*?

Comment: I have studied linear regression graph and I created Y=mx+n line in my graph and I want to draw %95 one tailed confidence interval up to previous line for example I want to find a value "c" and add previous line equation Y=mx+n+c so I will create new line which is 95% one tailed confidence interval but I didn't find and draw it.

Comment: The source code for some GIF animated curve fitting problems http://zunzun.com/CommonProblems/ has Python source code at https://bitbucket.org/zunzuncode/CommonProblems and includes 95% confidence intervals as part of the animations. I think this might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I want to create 95%line in your GIF graph but How can I draw it ? @JamesPhillips

Comment: In addition I wonder that Can I use seaborn to create 95% confidence line?

Comment: I personally do not use seaborn, so I cannot answer that question.

Comment: Ok thank James. Which method is suitable as a solution?